# database query returns null even if there is value in it

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my android app am trying to get values from database by passing one parameter to the where clause but it is always returning null...and theres no error in logcat...
i cant seem to figure out what is the issue here??

Please help!

the code where i am callimg the database function:

```
appmname=mDbHelper.getMname(appName);
             applname=mDbHelper.getLname(appmname);
             customername=appName+appmname+applname;
                // app_formno=mDbHelper.getAppno(settings.getString("ap_First_Name", ""));

             s=mDbHelper.fetchDetails(appName);
            s=mDbHelper.getMainData(customername);
```

these are the functions returning database values:

```
public String getMname(String fname)
{
    String mname = null;
    try
    {
        String sql="select app_mname from lnt_data_table where app_fname = '"+fname+"'";
        Cursor c=mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();

            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

                    mname=c.getString(0);
            }
            c.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mname;
}

public String getLname(String mname)
{
    String lname = null;
    try
    {
        String sql="select app_lname from lnt_data_table where app_mname= '"+mname+"'";
        Cursor c=mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToLast();

            while (c.isBeforeFirst() != true) {

                    lname=c.getString(0);
            }
            c.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lname;
}
```

if i give this toast message

```
Toast.makeText(ListViewDetails.this,appName+ appmname +applname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it returns null when the database has values in it!

Comment: try adding `SQLiteQueryBuilder mDb= new SQLiteQueryBuilder();` inside your method.. and check if there are logtraces..

Comment: follow this tutorial it will help you http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this format for calling the cursor and closing it

```
    if (cursor != null) {

      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

          do {
                       //your code

              }

           while (cursor.moveToNext());

         }

  cursor.close();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this still returns null value!:(

Comment: Can you write your query in the SQLite and see what result you are getting?

Comment: i am getting the required result if i run my query  there!

Comment: c.moveToFirst();
  if (c != null) {
   do {
   } while (c.moveToNext()); try this and see

Answer (score 1):

I think you are moving to the end of the `cursor` before actually getting anything from it. Try changing `c.moveToLast();` to `c.moveToFirst()` and then in the while loop just change `while (c.isBeforeFirst())` to `while(!c.isAfterLast())`

You are currently moving to the end of the cursor and then checking if its at a position before the first entry...which is kinda impossible. Probably why you aren't getting anything back

Comment: i did th required changes! see my edit! but still returning null!

Comment: are you sure there is a value for `fname`? you did open the database right? just trying to think of everything that could cause null.